# CM4 USB connection issues

Tags: raspbian, usb, kernel, hub

We have rolled our own board for the CM4 and the problem occours when connecting an UMTS stick (Huawei E3531 HiLink) to USB. The CM4 starts to disconnect and reconnect the stick continuously.
This behavior only happens sometimes and has probably nothing to do with the connection state of the stick (bad cellular connectivity won't affect power draw in any meaningful way).
We use a custom pcb with stable 5V supply voltage. The UMTS stick is directly connected to USB_N and USB_P without a hub in between.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this issue? First thought was a bad USB connection, or unstable voltages, but both cases have been tested. We also have tried upgrading all packages but to no avail.
This issue does not seem to occur when using the CM4 evaluation board.

Kernel: 5.10.63-v7l+

example dmesg dump:

```
[  126.209397] usb-storage 1-1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  126.211939] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.2
[  127.260219] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  127.260578] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  127.330704] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  133.019382] usb usb1-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[  133.019407] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  133.019636] cdc_ether 1-1:1.0 eth1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-fe980000.usb-1, CDC Ethernet Device
[  133.729210] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc2
[  133.980404] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
[  133.980423] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  133.980439] usb 1-1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[  133.980454] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[  134.101353] cdc_ether 1-1:1.0 eth1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-fe980000.usb-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
[  134.102193] usb-storage 1-1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  134.102848] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.2
[  135.170128] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  135.170729] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  135.221326] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  141.269091] usb usb1-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[  141.269105] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[  141.269231] cdc_ether 1-1:1.0 eth1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-fe980000.usb-1, CDC Ethernet Device
[  141.959040] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc2
[  142.219727] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
[  142.219737] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  142.219745] usb 1-1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[  142.219752] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[  142.338753] cdc_ether 1-1:1.0 eth1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-fe980000.usb-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
[  142.340196] usb-storage 1-1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  142.340631] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.2
[  143.420209] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  143.420567] scsi 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  143.471097] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  149.518983] usb usb1-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[  149.518997] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[  149.519125] cdc_ether 1-1:1.0 eth1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-fe980000.usb-1, CDC Ethernet Device
[  150.148940] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using dwc2
[  150.399841] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
[  150.399851] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  150.399858] usb 1-1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[  150.399866] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[  150.528572] cdc_ether 1-1:1.0 eth1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-fe980000.usb-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
[  150.529142] usb-storage 1-1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  150.529533] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.2
[  151.579693] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  151.580035] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  151.631315] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  157.768936] usb usb1-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[  157.768951] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[  157.769073] cdc_ether 1-1:1.0 eth1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-fe980000.usb-1, CDC Ethernet Device
[  158.458847] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using dwc2
[  158.709083] usb 1-1: device descriptor read/all, error -71
[  158.928888] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 10 using dwc2
[  159.179775] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
[  159.179785] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  159.179792] usb 1-1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[  159.179800] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[  159.251329] dwc2 fe980000.usb: dwc2_hc_chhltd_intr_dma: Channel 1 - ChHltd set, but reason is unknown
[  159.251337] dwc2 fe980000.usb: hcint 0x00000002, intsts 0x04400029
[  159.251390] usb 1-1: can't set config #1, error -71
[  386.228855] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 10
[  399.668757] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 11 using dwc2
[  399.920044] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1f01, bcdDevice= 1.02
[  399.920067] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  399.920085] usb 1-1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[  399.920102] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[  399.920119] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
[  399.934524] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  399.935204] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[  400.978976] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 11
[  401.408761] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 12 using dwc2
[  401.659551] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
[  401.659561] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  401.659568] usb 1-1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
[  401.659576] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
[  401.768607] cdc_ether 1-1:1.0 eth1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-fe980000.usb-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
[  401.769238] usb-storage 1-1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  401.770914] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.2
[  402.849468] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   TF CARD Storage  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  402.849908] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  402.900229] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  423.978931] usb usb1-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[  423.978956] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 12
[  423.979187] cdc_ether 1-1:1.0 eth1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-fe980000.usb-1, CDC Ethernet Device
[  425.748780] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  427.068910] usb usb1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[  427.069000] usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
```

journalctl dump of another time this issue has occurred:

```
Dec 23 11:40:31 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 32 using dwc2
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: can't set config #1, error -71
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: usb usb1-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 32
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 33 using dwc2
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/all, error -71
Dec 23 11:40:32 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 34 using dwc2
Dec 23 11:40:33 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
Dec 23 11:40:33 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Dec 23 11:40:33 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
Dec 23 11:40:33 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
Dec 23 11:40:33 test-pi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1:1.0 eth1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-fe980000.usb-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
Dec 23 11:40:33 test-pi kernel: usb-storage 1-1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
Dec 23 11:40:33 test-pi kernel: scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.2
Dec 23 11:40:33 test-pi kernel: usb usb1-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
Dec 23 11:40:33 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 34
Dec 23 11:40:33 test-pi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1:1.0 eth1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-fe980000.usb-1, CDC Ethernet Device
Dec 23 11:40:38 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 35 using dwc2
Dec 23 11:40:38 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:38 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:38 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:38 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:38 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:38 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:38 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:38 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:38 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:39 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 23 11:40:39 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
Dec 23 11:40:39 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Dec 23 11:40:39 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
Dec 23 11:40:39 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
Dec 23 11:40:39 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:39 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: can't set config #1, error -71
Dec 23 11:40:39 test-pi kernel: usb usb1-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
Dec 23 11:40:39 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 35
Dec 23 11:40:39 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 36 using dwc2
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: can't set config #1, error -71
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: usb usb1-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 36
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 37 using dwc2
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:40 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/all, error -71
Dec 23 11:40:41 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 38 using dwc2
Dec 23 11:40:41 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
Dec 23 11:40:41 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Dec 23 11:40:41 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
Dec 23 11:40:41 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
Dec 23 11:40:41 test-pi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1:1.0 eth1: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-fe980000.usb-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 00:1e:10:1f:00:00
Dec 23 11:40:41 test-pi kernel: usb-storage 1-1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
Dec 23 11:40:41 test-pi kernel: scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.2
Dec 23 11:40:42 test-pi kernel: usb usb1-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
Dec 23 11:40:42 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 38
Dec 23 11:40:42 test-pi kernel: cdc_ether 1-1:1.0 eth1: unregister 'cdc_ether' usb-fe980000.usb-1, CDC Ethernet Device
Dec 23 11:40:42 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 39 using dwc2
Dec 23 11:40:42 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:42 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:42 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:42 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:42 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:42 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:42 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:42 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:42 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: string descriptor 0 read error: -71
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=14dc, bcdDevice= 1.02
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: can't set config #1, error -71
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: usb usb1-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 39
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 40 using dwc2
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:43 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/all, error -71
Dec 23 11:40:44 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 41 using dwc2
Dec 23 11:40:44 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:44 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:44 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:44 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:44 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:44 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:44 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:44 test-pi kernel: dwc2 fe980000.usb: NYET/NAK/ACK/other in non-error case, 0x00000002
Dec 23 11:40:44 test-pi kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/all, error -71
Dec 23 11:40:44 test-pi kernel: usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
```

somewhat relevant dtoverlays:

```
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=uart4
dtoverlay=uart2
dtoverlay=uart3
dtoverlay=uart5
# Enable USB Interface
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=host
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a hardware problem, somehow.

Some background: The message is probably generated by  `drivers/usb/hub.c`; the comment section above it says:

```
/*
* EM interference sometimes causes bad shielded USB devices to
* be shutdown by the hub, this hack enables them again.
* Works at least with mouse driver.
*/
```

The real reason needs some investigation. Your UMTS stick may be faulty. Sometimes, it really is EMI, and an extension cable between the Pi and the stick may move it far enough not to get EMI. Sometimes, explicitly grounding the Pi works as well.

Comment: Thanks for your input, it indeed is a hardware problem, more specifically there is a problem with the USB termination.

We opened a new thread for this problem: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135573/missing-usb-termination-on-cm4